# Is there a reliable way to find out if people are still using a domain as a name server?

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name, nameserver

I had a domain I was using for a nameserver with my hosting.  I had to move hosting, but due to propagation all of the sites and/or emails could potentially go down as I moved the nameserver across.  The domain was tied to the hosting account on cPanel so I couldn't simply start the new service.

To resolve this issue I decided to create the new host and assign a new domain name to it.  Then I copied the websites across along with the configuration.

Finally, I asked the clients to update their DNS/Nameserver/A records to complete the migration.

I now have two domain names and I don't need both.  And one is due to expire.  So my question is... is there a reliable way to check if anyone is still accidentally on the old domain name before I stop renewing that domain name?  I have a fair few customers, I don't have all of their DNS, some are hosted elsewhere too, I just want to make sure I don't kill anyone's email or website by accident.

Comment: Have you checked server logs?

Comment: it's a domain though, not a server.  Can I still do that?